# Unable to change the background image of the button in uiTableview if once set

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

Her tableAllconacts is my nsmutablearray

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;


        btnChk =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btnChk.frame =CGRectMake(280, 4, 32, 32);
        btnChk.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
        [btnChk addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCheckmarkClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btnChk.tag=indexPath.row;


        UIImageView *separator=[[UIImageView alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 1)];
        separator.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider.png"];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:separator];

    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
    cell.textLabel.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = [appdeleObj.arrDriverName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




    NSString *strValue=[appdeleObj.arrDriverName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"%@",strValue);

        if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"Checked"]isEqualToString:strValue] )

        {

            if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults ] boolForKey:@"showChkmark"] )

            {

       [btnChk setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];            

        }
            else
            {

                [btnChk setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            }
        }
        else

        {
            NSLog(@"%@",btnChk.currentBackgroundImage);
            [btnChk setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:btnChk];
    return cell;

}
```

Button Action

```
-(void)btnCheckmarkClicked: (UIButton *)sender
{

  CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableAllContacts];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableAllContacts indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];

// No need to use tag sender will keep the reference of clicked button
  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    appdeleObj.strCheckUnchek =[appdeleObj.arrDriverName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([button.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_on.png"]])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"radio_off.png" forKey:@"Checked"];
     //   [button setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"showChkmark"];

    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:appdeleObj.strCheckUnchek forKey:@"Checked"];
   // [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"showChkmark"];


    }

    [tableAllContacts reloadData];

}
```

Comment: First of all check the NSUserDefaults value it is changing or ont

Comment: The values in the nsuserdefaults is changing perfectly but the set background image is not updating when all the checks above are working  properly

Comment: ok then remove the condition of the cell==nil]

Comment: I have answered to your question . Just see it and let me know if you need any more details .

Answer (score 0):

1. Line of code to change the background image is commented in the code you posted.
2. You are creating the button inside the method.

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   ```

This will draw the button always you reload the table. My suggestion is to try creating the button outside the above method and just set the tag inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   -(void)btnCheckmarkClicked: (UIButton *)sender
    {

      CGPoint touchPoint = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tableAllContacts];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableAllContacts indexPathForRowAtPoint:touchPoint];

    // No need to use tag sender will keep the reference of clicked button
      UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

        appdeleObj.strCheckUnchek =[appdeleObj.arrDriverName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if ([button.currentBackgroundImage isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_on.png"]])
        {
//Update the BackGround Image When you click the button
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"radio_off.png" forKey:@"Checked"];
         //   [button setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"showChkmark"];

        }
        else
        {

    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:appdeleObj.strCheckUnchek forKey:@"Checked"];
       // [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"showChkmark"];


        }

        [tableAllContacts reloadData];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you .

In the 
`if(cell == nil)` condition write this .

```
btnChk =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnChk.frame =CGRectMake(280, 4, 32, 32);
btnChk.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
[btnChk addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCheckmarkClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnChk.tag=indexPath.row;
[cell.contentView addSubview:btnChk]; //added this line to your code.
```

Out side the if condition get the same button like this using the tag

```
UIButton *btn2 = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
```

now apply your image on this button .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing so, why don't you set the two background images for the different states of the button like below?

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_on.png"]
                  forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_off.png"]
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And then you can just invert the value of the `button.selected` field in `-(void)btnCheckmarkClicked: (UIButton *)sender`; then the button will update its backgroundImage automatically for you.

```
button.selected = !button.selected;
```

Hope this helps.