# Unable to change UIButton image inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` created in a xib and have assigned it a class file of it's own. I have assigned a background image to a `UIButton` inside this custom cell in IB. In my `ViewController` where I have a `UITableView` that uses this cell, I have the below code.

```
 _yesNoCell = (YesNoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YesNoCell"];

 // Below code is not working    
 [_yesNoCell.btnYes setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"action_selected"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];

 [_yesNoCell.btnYes addTarget:self action:@selector(btnYesTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Everything works fine, and the `btnYesTap` method gets called as expected. The background image set in IB shows up, however, what I want is to set a different image when the button is pressed down (not released) i.e the `UIControlStateHighlighted`. The code above is not working.

I even tried add an action to the button as :

```
 [_yesNoCell.btnYes addTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

And change the image in `changeImage` method, but it didn't work.

I referred to similar posts on SO, but none of them seem to have a solution. Referred links : [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895240/how-to-change-the-button-image-inside-the-table-cell-while-clicking-the-button-i?rq=1) [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114177/uibutton-within-uitableviewcell-is-tappablegetting-proper-event-but-the-issue/42115543) [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306569/unable-to-change-the-background-image-of-the-button-in-uitableview-if-once-set?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are changing button image for Highlighted state,
I think you should set image for normal state like
[_yesNoCell.btnYes setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"action_selected"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich : That's what I want, I want to show a different image on the button when it's pressed down (and not yet released).

Comment: I test above code and it's working for me

Comment: please verify your image is not empty

Comment: and you hold button for couple of seconds

Answer (score 0):

Actually you setting the button image at Highlighted state but your button is at normal (default) state. So change your button state as like below.

Swift 4

```
    let myImg = UIImage(named: "your-img-name") // your image
    myButton.setImage(myImg, for: .highlighted) // set button image for state
    myButton.isHighlighted = true // change button state
```

Objective-C

```
UIImage *myImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your-img-name"];
[myButton setImage:myImg forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[myButton setHighlighted:true];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that using `UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted`

```
[_yesNoCell.btnYes setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"action_selected"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```